# How to get the name of the Master Frame in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter, widget

to cut a long story short: Is there a function to get the name of the Master Frame of a widget in Tkinter?

Let me tell you a little bit more:

There is a Button, named "BackButton"

```
self.BackButton = Button(self.SCPIFrame, text = "Back", command = self.CloseFrame)
self.BackButton.place(x = 320, y = 320, anchor = CENTER)
```

When I click on this Button, there is a function named "CloseFrame", which closes the current Frame (and doing some other stuff), in this case "SCPIFrame". But for this, I need the name of the Frame, in which the BackButton is present.
Any ideas? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To literally answer your question:

> Is there a function to get the name of the Master Frame of a widget in
>   Tkinter?

`winfo_parent` is exactly what you need. To be useful, you can use it combined with `_nametowidget` (since `winfo_parent` actually returns the name of the parent).

```
parent_name = widget.winfo_parent()
parent = widget._nametowidget(parent_name)
```

Comment: When I try to print the parent name of the BackButton, I get a number:
.33500616. 
`self.parent_name = self.BackButton.winfo_parent()`
`print self.parent_name`

Comment: This number is the Tcl variable name. `_nametowidget` retrieves the corresponding Tkinter instance.Talking of **the** name of an object is a bit dubious since many variables can be bound to this object. However, we are in a case where Tkinter indirection on top of Tcl provides an unique _name_ as Tcl variable name.

Answer (score 12):

I think the best way is to use the .master attribute, which is literally the master's instance :)
For example (I am doing this in IPython):

```
import Tkinter as tk

# We organize a 3-level widget hierarchy:
# root
#   frame
#     button

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)    
frame.pack()
button = tk.Button(frame, text="Privet!", background='tan')
button.pack()

# Now, let's try to access all the ancestors 
# of the "grandson" button:

button.master   # Father of the button is the frame instance:
<Tkinter.Frame instance at 0x7f47e9c22128>

button.master.master   # Grandfather of the button, root, is the frame's father:
<Tkinter.Tk instance at 0x7f47e9c0def0>

button.master.master.master  # Empty result - the button has no great-grand-father ;)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the widget naming convention has changed in Python 3, the easiest way to do this now is as follows:

For the top Tk() window,

```
<anywidget>.nametowidget('.')
```

And for the only Toplevel window:

```
<anywidget>.nametowidget('.!toplevel')
```

But the `.master` attribute still works, too, in case you want to be backwards compatible:

```
def patriarch(widget):
    while widget and widget.master:
        widget = widget.master
    return widget
```

Keep in mind that all widgets trace back to '.' in Python 3, including the Toplevels. So if you don't actually want the patriarch, but rather the window in which a widget is mapped, you could use this, by setting `window_b` to True:

```
def patriarch(widget, window_b=False):
    while widget and widget.master:
        widget = widget.master
        if window_b and isinstance(widget, tk.Toplevel):
            break
    return widget
```

And if you prefer to find the top window that has the widget mapped, you can use something like this:

```
def window_by_str(widget):
    widget_s = str(widget)
    if (pos := widget_s.rfind('!toplevel')) == -1:
        window = "."
    elif (pos := widget_s.find('.', pos) == -1:
        window = widget_s
    else:
        window = widget_s[:pos]
    return widget.nametowidget(window)
```