# Getting the parent of a parent widget in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, parent

I am trying to get the parent of a widget then get the parent of that widget. But Everytime I try to I get a error.

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_nametowidget'
```

Why is it giving me that error. Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error and help me to fix it?

Code:

```
parent = event.widget.winfo_parent()
parentName = event.widget._nametowidget(parent)

frameParent = parentName.winfo_parent()
frameParentName = frameParent._nametowidget(frameParent)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm

Mentions as below, winfo_parent() is a method to get parent's name.

The error you get means that event.widget doesn't has the method named _nametowidget.
So you could not call that as a function.

You may try codes below to get the parent.

```
parent = event.widget.winfo_parent()
from Tkinter import Widget
Widget._nametowidget(parent)
```

Comment: I think you have miss interpreted what I am asking I have a label in a Text widget then that text widget is in a frame. I want to get the frame so I can access what is in it (The widgets in it). And I can not jsut use its name because I use a for look and create multiple frames witht he same name "self.frame".

Comment: I understand that winfo_parent() always return a name of a widget's parent name, its type is `str`, and `str` always has no attribute '_nametowidget' to call. You could not call _nametowidget() from a `str` object.

Comment: @0Cool Why do you make several frames with the same name? Just give them different names or keep reference to all frames in a list if you create them in a loop.

Answer (score 16):

```
grandparent = event.widget.master.master
```

See the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42425449/7550928).

Answer (score 0):

Your second call to _nametowidget() is different than your first. Your fourth line is bad, since you're basing the call to _nametowidget() on a string (frameParent) instead of on a widget (parentName). This is partly because your naming convention of "widget" and "widgetName" is reversed...

frameParentName = frameParent._nametowidget(frameParent)

```
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ -- this is the name string. you need a widget
```

I would slightly rewrite your code as follows:

```
parentName = event.widget.winfo_parent()
parent     = event.widget._nametowidget(parentName) #event.widget is your widget

frameParentName = parent.winfo_parent()
frameParent     = parent._nametowidget(frameParentName) #parent is your widget
```